# testing collinearity in MLM

Tags: r, mixed-model

Given this linear mixed model

```
dat <- data.frame(blocks = rep(1:15, each = 2), 
                  soil = runif(30, 0, 10), 
                  nitro = runif(30, 0, 10), 
                  temp = rnorm(30, 10, 3)) 

mod <- lmer(soil ~ nitro * temp + (1 | blocks), data = dat)
```

How can I check if there is multi-collinearity between the predictors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assess the level of multi-colinearity between you predictors you can calculate the [variance inflation factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor). The function `vif()` from the **car** package should work for linear mixed models fitted by `lmer()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have created the variables by sampling from a normal distribution where each variable is sampled independently of the others. Therefore there should be no multicollinearity between the variables, however there will be high correlation between the variables and the interaction term:

```
> set.seed(22)
> dat <- data.frame(blocks = rep(1:15, each = 2), 
                   soil = runif(30, 0, 10), 
                   nitro = runif(30, 0, 10), 
                   temp = rnorm(30, 10, 3)) 

> mm <- model.matrix(soil ~ nitro * temp, dat)

> cor(mm[, -1])

                nitro       temp nitro:temp
nitro       1.0000000 -0.1860283  0.8950713
temp       -0.1860283  1.0000000  0.1661519
nitro:temp  0.8950713  0.1661519  1.0000000
```

As per the answer by Dimitris, you can assess the impact of this through the variance inflation factors.